# php symfony setting nested parameters in container

Tags: php, symfony

In my php symfony app I got the following `parameters.yml`:

```
my_param: some_value
my_nested:
    param: some_value2 //4 spaces here, need to set only this param
    param2: some_value3 // this should NOT be changed
```

I can set the parameter in a container with the following code:

```
$container->setParameter('my_param', $some_value);
```

it works fine, but I need to set a nested parameters, like this:

```
$container->setParameter('my_nested.param', $some_value);
```

I get an error saying that it cannot set nested param. Any ideas how to fix that? `my_nested.param2` (and other nested params here) should not be changed.  Thank you.

Comment: how many spaces are there on that third line? It matters. And I hate that fact! Space sensitive context sucks.

Comment: 4 spaces, added to question info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an array-like structure, like this:

```
$container->setParameter('my_nested', [
  'param' => $some_value_2,
]);
```

Have a look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

An example to change a nested parameter:

```
$container->setParameter('my_nested', [
  'top' => [
    'nested' => 'a',
  ]
]);

$parameter = $container->getParameter('my_nested');
$parameter['top']['nested'] = 'b';

$container->setParameter('my_nested', $parameter);
```

Comment: yes, but what if there are some more nested params there and I need to set only 1 of them. The others get deleted unfortunately

Comment: Masha, in that case use array_merge with getParameter!

Comment: You can do `getParameter('xxx')`, then change the array and `setParameter('xxx', $array)`

Comment: i tested your code ,but no way , symfony return the error :Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.

Comment: If that's the case, why is this marked as the correct answer? I'm confused

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI where are you calling that? Once the application boots and the container sets services and parameters, it gets frozen, and it won't allow any changes to it (but it can be then cached for faster bootstrapping, for example).

Comment: I assume you're trying to set parameters inside the controller or something... That's not possible. Don't use the container as a session holder or something

Comment: i tried your code ,but sorry to say  your code not working , and getting error "symfony return the error :Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag"

Answer (score 1):

you can define the value like that :

the parameters.yml :

```
    parameters:        
        my_param: some_value
        my_nested.param: some_value2
```

you can get the value as you show in your description , but modify this value is impossible . 
symfony will notify you with the error :

> Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.

Comment: How do you thaw out a frozen bag of parameters?

Comment: i think is not possible .

Comment: it seems you want to persist some kind of permanent modification. In that case consider using session